# Where can I find my Enterprise ID for Box API?

Tags: box-api

I'm using the Box API SDK for .Net, and trying to set it up to use JSON Web Tokens instead of OAuth2.

When I instantiate the BoxConfig object I need to provide the Enterprise ID:

```
var config = new BoxConfig( clientId, clientSecret, enterpriseId, jwtPrivateKey, jwtPrivateKeyPassword, jwtPublicKeyId );
```

Seeing some conflicting information:

- The [GitHub page for the Box Java SDK](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk) says the Enterprise ID is
  on the developer console, but I don't see it there.
- The [Box API help page for App Auth](https://box-content.readme.io/v2.0/docs/app-auth) says it's in the Admin
  Console, but I don't see it there either.

Can someone point me to where, specifically, I could find the Enterprise ID?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the Enterprise ID by going to the Admin Console -> Click the gear in the top right -> Click Business Settings (It may say Enterprise Settings or Elite Settings based on the account level). Under the Account Info tab you can see your Enterprise ID.

You can also get directly to that page by going to
https://www.box.com/master/settings while logged into the account. Note that only enterprise admins / co-admins with sufficient permissions will have access to that page, otherwise it will redirect to the account settings. In this case, you would need to contact your enterprise admin to get this Enterprise ID.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I just didn't have the access to see it. Had to ask my boss' boss.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the Enterprise ID is embedded on most pages, even the */files* page. It can be accessed by opening the browser's console and entering in `window.initialConfig["enterpriseId"]` or `console.log(window.initialConfig["enterpriseId"]);`.

Even though that will give you the Enterprise ID the application will still need to be approved by an Enterprise Admin.

Comment: should that still work?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the Developer Console for your app under "Configuration" > "App Settings" where you will see a JSON representation of your App Settings JSON file that you can also download. The Enterprise ID is the `enterpriseID` property.

[image: Box App Settings JSON File]